# AWS Route 53. What does the 53 stand for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I know Route53 is a domain name system used for routing but what is the 53 reference to?

I looked up a few [articles](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stands for the port it is using. DNS's port is 53. 
That's it. 
Check [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#DNS_protocol_transport).